# wpf intelligent grid layout

Tags: wpf, layout, uniformgrid

I am currently working on a project which contains a window, that has a need to display between 1 and 9 user controls.

I am looking for the best way to ensure that the full space available is used by the number of user controls selected.

e.g. if 9 items are selected then a grid of 3 x 3 is displayed. However if 8 are selected then 2 rows of 3 would be shown with a row of 2 below. (using a colspan).

I have been trying to use a uniform grid as this looks as though most of the desired behaviour already exists. (displays items in the ordered added, auto resizes to window size). However I'm struggling to implement some form of intelligence when the number of items selected is not divisible by 3!

Has anybody encountered this problem before? Or can suggest a suitable way to solve the problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `WrapPanel` and setting the `Width` of each object to 1/3 of the wrap panel's size.

This will automatically move items to a new row when the first row fills up

Comment: I will investigate using a wrap panel and setting the width of the objects to 1/3 of the wrap panels size. I will have to check for the mod on the item count to calculate the last items width. Thanks.

Comment: In the end I have come up with a solution which uses a wrap panel, each time an item is added to the panel. I calculate the number of rows and the number of controls on each row and set the height and width of each item to a fraction of the panel height and width.

Comment: @Rachel the UniformGrid accomplishes the same thing as what you have described, but I think it's more flexible because it doesn't require any hard-coded values (via XAML), or any code behind at all.  Just set the number of Columns and the width gets calculated automatically.

Comment: @Dave `WrapPanel` is a little different from a `UniformGrid` because all the items do not have to be the same size. If you have a couple items that will be a different size based on the total number of items in the Panel, then it is much easier to do that in a `WrapPanel` than a `UniformGrid`

Comment: @Rachel I understand... I was just commenting purely based off of what I had read in your answer, which addresses the issue of sharing space for 3 controls, and allowing additional controls to overflow to the next row.  The UniformGrid does just that.  However, since the OP actually wants to share the space for **<= 3** controls per row equally, I agree that the WrapPanel is a much better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the uniform grid.  Since it sounds like you want 3 columns, regardless of the number of controls displayed, you just have to use:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3" />
```

And it will do what you've asked for -- if you have 8 controls, you'll get 2x3 + 2 extra below.

Comment: This does give the two rows of three items but the last two items are not stretched horizontally into the remaining space. This leaves one empty space for an item which is what I'm trying to avoid. Thanks

Comment: @53AN ah, sorry, I didn't realize that you wanted the last two to stretch out like that.